# Matrix join in SQL ?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have two Tables objects  and attributes

```
objects
   id (integer)
   name (string)

attributes
   idd (integer)
   value (string)
```

And these values:

```
1,A
2,B
3,C

1,X
2,Y
3,Z
4,P
5,Q
```

I'd like to get this:

```
ID | IDD | Value
1 | 1 |X
1 | 2 |y
1 | 3 |Z
1 | 4 |P
1 | 5 |Q
2 | 1 |X
2 | 2 |y
2 | 3 |Z
2 | 4 |P
2 | 5 |Q
3 | 1 |X
3 | 2 |y
3 | 3 |Z
3 | 4 |P
3 | 5 |Q
```

Its just a Cross join in different tables which is the best way to do it

Comment: @Farhęg - i tried cross Join and it works . Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome, but I don't see my comment and don't know how and why it has deleted, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @Farhęg said...

```
select a.ID, b.* from objects a
cross join attributes b
order by a.ID, b.Idd
```

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/124a3/1

```
SELECT o.id, a.idd, a.value
FROM attributes a
LEFT JOIN objects o
ON 1
```